# How to report someone who is wrong at marked your question as "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Okay, wonder if this question will be mark as duplicate. But I get this more than one, I may be a "bad asker" in the future, but this really pissed me off that I ask a question, than there are people who marked it as "duplicate" even that the question they give me do not relate to my question.

I won't say I was right at all, because there are many others people that don't get this problem.

But sometimes I feel that the one who marked my question as "duplicate" didn't even read what's happening in that question.

So how could I at least tell them that "you're wrong, please take a look at the content instead of the title" ? In an effective way?

Comment: [question this rant is about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420085/variable-inside-echo-php)

Comment: This question **is correctly** marked as duplicate IMO. The linked question does exactly what you are trying to accomplish, you just seem to be missing the ability to abstract the actual code away to the approach.

Comment: @gnat A duplicate for a question on duplicates is so incredibly good here.

Comment: @gnat A duplicate for a question on duplicates is so incredibly good here.

Comment: @lexicore [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274656/how-to-report-someone-who-is-wrong-at-marked-your-question-as-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment106824_274656) [comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274656/how-to-report-someone-who-is-wrong-at-marked-your-question-as-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment106825_274656) about duplicate for a question on duplicates aren't bad either

Comment: Irony is rich....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't report them.

Assuming that your question is not a duplicate you do the following:

1. Edit your question to make it clear that it's different. This will place it in the reopen review queue where it will looked at by other users and if enough of them agree it will be reopened.
2. There is no step 2.

If you can't highlight the differences then there's a good chance that your question *is* in fact a duplicate and was correctly closed.

Comment: Asking folks on Meta to check out the situation, and vote to reopen if warranted, is a legitimate step too, if the OP is really sure there has been a grave mistake. (There hasn't in this specific case, though.)

Comment: @Pekka웃: please god *nooo* don't advise everyone-and-his-pet-peeve to "raise it on Meta". The current system is: 5 regular (or 1 Golden Ticket) Close Votes to close; 5 reopen votes to reopen. If an OP cannot find 5 people to agree on re-opening a question, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @Jongware the reopen mechanism is traditionally a bit broken and by far not every question that deserves reopening actually is. Asking to reopen on Meta is a perfectly valid option.